# Collecting the statistics of disk usage using oVirt

Tags: linux, rhel, ovirt

I used the REST-API to collect the statistics of a Virtual Disk using oVirt REST API and I got the following response,

```
https://1.1.1.1/ovirt-engine/api/disks/b14da816-37e3-46d7-8617-2e42e52db996/statistics/
```

Response to this ***API***,

```
{
  "statistic": [{
    "kind": "gauge",
    "type": "decimal",
    "unit": "bytes_per_second",
    "values": {
      "value": [{
        "datum": 0
      }]
    },
    "disk": {
      "href": "/ovirt-engine/api/disks/b14da816-37e3-46d7-8617-2e42e52db996",
      "id": "b14da816-37e3-46d7-8617-2e42e52db996"
    },
    "name": "data.current.read",
    "description": "Read data rate",
    "href": "/ovirt-engine/api/disks/b14da816-37e3-46d7-8617-2e42e52db996/statistics/33b9212b-f9cb-3fd0-b364-248fb61e1272",
    "id": "33b9212b-f9cb-3fd0-b364-248fb61e1272"
  }, {
    "kind": "gauge",
    "type": "decimal",
    "unit": "bytes_per_second",
    "values": {
      "value": [{
        "datum": 0
      }]
    },
    "disk": {
      "href": "/ovirt-engine/api/disks/b14da816-37e3-46d7-8617-2e42e52db996",
      "id": "b14da816-37e3-46d7-8617-2e42e52db996"
    },
    "name": "data.current.write",
    "description": "Write data rate",
    "href": "/ovirt-engine/api/disks/b14da816-37e3-46d7-8617-2e42e52db996/statistics/2f23addd-4ebd-3d82-a449-c28778bc33eb",
    "id": "2f23addd-4ebd-3d82-a449-c28778bc33eb"
  }, {
    "kind": "gauge",
    "type": "decimal",
    "unit": "seconds",
    "values": {
      "value": [{
        "datum": 0
      }]
    },
    "disk": {
      "href": "/ovirt-engine/api/disks/b14da816-37e3-46d7-8617-2e42e52db996",
      "id": "b14da816-37e3-46d7-8617-2e42e52db996"
    },
    "name": "disk.read.latency",
    "description": "Read latency",
    "href": "/ovirt-engine/api/disks/b14da816-37e3-46d7-8617-2e42e52db996/statistics/3a7b3f72-d035-3bb9-b196-e86a4eb34993",
    "id": "3a7b3f72-d035-3bb9-b196-e86a4eb34993"
  }, {
    "kind": "gauge",
    "type": "decimal",
    "unit": "seconds",
    "values": {
      "value": [{
        "datum": 0
      }]
    },
    "disk": {
      "href": "/ovirt-engine/api/disks/b14da816-37e3-46d7-8617-2e42e52db996",
      "id": "b14da816-37e3-46d7-8617-2e42e52db996"
    },
    "name": "disk.write.latency",
    "description": "Write latency",
    "href": "/ovirt-engine/api/disks/b14da816-37e3-46d7-8617-2e42e52db996/statistics/b1e75c7b-cea4-37d2-8459-f7d68efc69a3",
    "id": "b1e75c7b-cea4-37d2-8459-f7d68efc69a3"
  }, {
    "kind": "gauge",
    "type": "decimal",
    "unit": "seconds",
    "values": {
      "value": [{
        "datum": 0
      }]
    },
    "disk": {
      "href": "/ovirt-engine/api/disks/b14da816-37e3-46d7-8617-2e42e52db996",
      "id": "b14da816-37e3-46d7-8617-2e42e52db996"
    },
    "name": "disk.flush.latency",
    "description": "Flush latency",
    "href": "/ovirt-engine/api/disks/b14da816-37e3-46d7-8617-2e42e52db996/statistics/9c17ad7b-9ef1-3e8d-ad0a-ff8bee3925f0",
    "id": "9c17ad7b-9ef1-3e8d-ad0a-ff8bee3925f0"
  }]
}
```

So As per my understanding, It is able to retrieve 5 statistics (***i.e***) Read and Write Bandwidth, Read, Write and Flush Latency.

My question is, Is it possible to get the ***READ / WRITE IOPS*** of virtual disk / VM?

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 0):

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=876697 seems to answer this question. It states that, for ovirt-engine-metrics version 3.0.7:

> the collectd metrics per vm per disk from virt plugin metrics, is sufficient for this RFE.
>
> collectd.virt.disk_ops.read
> collectd.virt.disk_ops.write
>
> These metrics should allow the user to quickly / easily identify the VMs that utilized high I/O as requested in this RFE.
>
> Disk name is saved as collectd.type_instance.
> VM name is saved as collectd.plugin_instance.
>
> As for being able to aggregate storage IOPS per VM, it is not possible at this stage, since the disk name is not the drive name - it's what libvirt guesses, therefore it can't be aggregated across vms. User can log to the vm in order to be check the drive name.

AND

> Aggregation part will be solved in separate BZ. Verified in ovirt-engine-metrics-1.1.3.3-1.el7ev.noarch